# KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP(DOWN) registering double hits

Tags: android, button, volume

I have a simple app where I do the following:

```
public void onClick(View v){

    switch(v.getId()) {     
        case R.id.buttonup:
            onButtonUp();
            break;

        case R.id.buttondown:
            onButtonDown();
            break;
    }

}

public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event){
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        switch (keyCode) {

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
             onButtonUp();
             return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            onButtonDown();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);

        }

    }

void onButtonUp(){
    increment_some_static_class_variable;
}

void onButtonUp(){
    decrement_some_static_class_variable;
}
```

The thing is, whenever I press volume buttons, the onButtonUp and onButtondown functions are called twice. This does not happen when I press on screen buttons (handled in onClick(View)). I didn't find anybody having this issue so I am asking the folks here. I am new to Android and this is my first Application. Using Log, I found that both calls to onButtonUp and onButtonDown are coming from dispatchKeyEvent function. What could be wrong here? I hope I explained the problem well. Suggestions/Solutions are most welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KeyEvent can represent multiple actions, specifically both ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP. Since you aren't checking the action in your dispatchKeyEvent callback you are calling your button click methods for both DOWN and UP events on the volume buttons. Try like this:

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event){
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch (keyCode) {

            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                 onButtonUp();
                 return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                onButtonDown();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks FoamyGuy for your answer. Makes ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN very clear :-) I just added return false; outside the if statement. Hope that is right.

Comment: AFAIK false is fine for all intents and purposes but another option you have is `return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);`